# Execution of ls command in Linux

Tags: linux, glob

I don't understand the execution when `??` and `*` are used together.

The following files are in the current working directory:

> abc.txt
>   abcd.txt
>   bcd.txt
>   amm.doc
>   ammc.txt

What is the return result after executing command `ls a??.*`

Comment: What do you mean "what is the return result"?  What happened when you tried it?

Comment: In this pattern, the wild cards combine quite intuitively. It gets complicated when you remove the `.` between them, or have the `?` after the `*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 * Matches any string, including the null string (empty string)
 ? Matches any single character
```

For exemples

```
 Pattern a??.* matches abc.txt
```

- (a,a)
 - (?,b)
 - (?,c)
 - (.,.)
 - (*,txt)

```
 Pattern a??.* don't matches abcd.txt
```

- (a,a)
 - (?,b)
 - (?,c)
 - but . dont' matches with d

```
Pattern a??.* don't matches bcd.txt because a don't matches with b.
```

Answer (score 0):

The questions marks will translate to any one character but the * will translate to multiple characters. Your example will only produce abc.txt and amm.doc. Look up Shell Globbing if you want to know more.